# What constraints can be on the Fourier coefficients of $f(t)$ if $0 \leq f(t) \leq 1 $

Tags: fourier-series, constraints

Let's say $f(t)$ is a periodic and bounded signal, so it can be represented with Fourier series:

$f(t)= a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\mathbf{cos}(n\omega _0t) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n\mathbf{sin}(n\omega _0t)$

If $0 \leq f(t) \leq 1 $, what constraints can be on $a_0$, $a_n$ and $b_n$ ($n \geq 1 $)?

Comment: Is $f(t)$ continuous?

Comment: Yes. $f(t)$ is continuous

Comment: Tell us about what you tried.

Comment: Well I don't know even what I can try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Parseval equation we get
$$
\frac{a_0^2}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n^2+b_n^2)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\lvert f(x)\rvert^2\, dx\,
\leq
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dx\,
=2
$$

Comment: Thanks! I've forgotten the Parseval's theorem.